# How to write to out structure's field with Deviare?

Tags: c#, hook, deviare

I can use [Deviare](https://github.com/nektra/Deviare2) to hook and intercept `GetLocalTime` function, but how can I change field's value of its `out` parameter, i.e. edit `wYear` in `SYSTEMTIME`? Few snippets I could find use `NktHookCallInfo.Result`, unfortunately it's a void function and direct assignment to `Field(0).Value` does nothing.

```
CreateHook("kernel32.dll!GetLocalTime", (int)eNktHookFlags.flgOnlyPostCall);
```

```
private static void OnFunctionCalled(NktHook hook, NktProcess process, NktHookCallInfo info)
{
    NktParamsEnum param = info.Params();
    NktParam value = param.First().Evaluate();

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        NktParam field = value.Field(i);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", field.Name, field.TypeName, field.Value);
    }
}
```

```
void WINAPI GetLocalTime(
  _Out_ LPSYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime
);

typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

Comment: Does the code you typed in `OnFunctionCalled` display the values correctly? Using `field.Value = some-value;` should work.

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri Yes, I hook into notepad and click Edit > Time/Date menu to insert local date, it matches the struct console printout, but adding `value.Field(0).Value = 1999` has no effect.

Comment: Are you doing it in PostCall stage?

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri yes, it it only possibly in pre? I'm trying to change just one filed rather than recreate the whole structure. Is there an code sample by any chance?

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri Ok, so assigning to `Value` didn't work, but to `UShortVal` instead did and notepad inserted new date. Not quite sure why but it worked, thanks.

Comment: Excellent. We'll check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on comment is: Use `UShortVal`